# logkback warn No appenders present in context [default] for logger [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver]

Tags: spring-boot, logback

In my springboot3 app, i have a property in `application.yml`:

```
log:
  path:
    info: logs/datahub-info`
```

And my `logback-spring.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="60 seconds" debug="false">
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="FILE_PATH_INFO" source="log.path.info" defaultValue="logs/app1-info"/>
     <appender name="info-file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <!--日志文件输出的文件名 -->
        <File>${FILE_PATH_INFO}.log</File>
        ...everything else to config file log attributes...
     </appender>
     ...everything else config...
</configuration>
```

When running application, logging file is as expected, but such `logkback warn` occurs:

```bash
18:24:34,267 |-WARN in Logger[org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] - No appenders present in context [default] for logger [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver].
```

How to solve this warning?

Add `NopStatusListener` will erase everything from logback, but not solving this warn.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error while not using Spring to govern my application. I had to create a logback.xml in my resources folder like this:

```
<configuration debug="true">

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    
    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>    

</configuration>
```

I needed the `root` section. There's probably a way to assign an appender to whatever class is going to attempt to do logging, without depending on a root section.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem with Spring Boot 3. While the identical configuration worked perfectly in some microservices, in others, I received a WARNING. To resolve it, I simply added the following line to the properties:

```
logging.config = classpath:logback-spring.xml
```